# ValueError: shapes (1,6) and (5,5) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation, mlp

The NN must have 5 inputs, 4 hidden layers and 1 output. Learning rate 0.2, error threshold 0.2. Retrieves the data from an excel:
[image]

The error `ValueError: shapes (1,6) and (5,5) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)` is being displayed. I think I have something wrong with multiplying of weights and matrices the error line: `hidden_in = np.dot(inputs, w1)`. I can't seem to solve it. Can someone help?

```
def train(inputs_list, w1, w2, w3, targets_list, lr, error):
   ....
    while global_error > error:
        # local error
        local_error = np.array([])
   
        for i, inputs in enumerate(inputs_list):
            # translates the inputs sheet into a two-dimensional view (to enable the transposition operation)
            inputs = np.array(inputs, ndmin=2)
            print("Inputs", inputs)
            # targets - contains the local target for this input
            targets = np.array(targets_list[i], ndmin=2)
            print("Target should be 1", targets)
            # forward propagation
            # scalar product of string and weight matrix
            hidden_in = np.dot(inputs, w1)
            # apply an activation function to a vector
            hidden_out = f(hidden_in)
            # adding an imaginary unit to the beginning of the vector to train the network
            hidden_out = np.array(np.insert(hidden_out, 0, [1]), ndmin=2)
            # scalar product of string and weight matrix
            hidden_in2 = np.dot(hidden_out, w2)
            # apply an activation function to a vector
            hidden_out2 = f(hidden_in2)
            # adding an imaginary one to the beginning of the vector
            hidden_out2 = np.array(np.insert(hidden_out2, 0, [1]), ndmin=2)

            # scalar product of string and weight matrix
            final_in = np.dot(hidden_out2, w3)
            # the activation function of the output layer is a straight line y = x, so
            # here the value of "out" is equal to the value of "in"
            final_out = final_in

            # output layer error calculation
            output_error = targets - final_out

            # calculating the error of the second hidden layer
            hidden_error2 = np.dot(output_error, w3.T)
            # calculating the error of the first hidden layer
            hidden_error = np.dot(hidden_error2[:, 1:], w2.T)
            # adding the current error to the list of local errors
            local_error = np.append(local_error, output_error)
            # error backpropagation
            # changing the weight matrix 3 because derivative of the activation function (y = x)
            # y` = 1 in dW = lr*output_error*hidden_out2.T is not multiplied by this derivative
            w3 += lr * output_error * hidden_out2.T
            # in the backpropagation method, the imaginary one is excluded for the coincidence of dimensions
            # hidden_error2[:,1:] - means the whole vector except for the first element
            w2 += lr * hidden_error2[:, 1:] * f1(hidden_out2[:, 1:]) * hidden_out.T
            w1 += lr * hidden_error[:, 1:] * f1(hidden_out[:, 1:]) * inputs.T
        # global error is the module average of all local errors
        global_error = abs(np.mean(local_error))
        # global_error = np.sqrt(((local_error) ** 2).mean())
        last_gl_e = global_error
        # epoch incremented by 1
        era += 1
        # output to the console the current global error
        # print('era=',era, 'global_error=', global_error, 'k_sup=', k_sup)
        # a global error is added to the list of errors
        list_error.append(global_error)
        # if during training the number of epochs exceeds the threshold of 10000, then training will stop
        if era > 1000:
            print('gl=', global_error)
            break
        # returns the modified weights, number of epochs, and list of errors
    print(global_error)
    return w1, w2, w3, era, list_error


# function to test the trained network and output the result
def query(inputs_list, w1, w2, w3):
    # create a list in which we will store "outs" for the test set
    final_out = np.array([])
    for i, inputs in enumerate(inputs_list):
        # forward propagation just like training for "out"
        inputs = np.array(inputs, ndmin=2)

        hidden_in = np.dot(inputs, w1)
        hidden_out = f(hidden_in)
        hidden_out = np.array(np.insert(hidden_out, 0, [1]), ndmin=2)

        hidden_in2 = np.dot(hidden_out, w2)
        hidden_out2 = f(hidden_in2)
        hidden_out2 = np.array(np.insert(hidden_out2, 0, [1]), ndmin=2)

        final_in = np.dot(hidden_out2, w3)

        final_out = np.append(final_out, final_in)
    # return the value of the vector "out" rounded to an integer
    return np.around(final_out)


# read data from csv using pandas library
# Titanic Passenger Data
# Set the column that will be indexed index_col='PassengerId'
data_titanic = "titanic_dataset.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(data_titanic)
# column Survived from data
# .values ​​means that the data from the dataframe is converted to a numpy array
target_data = data['Survived'].values
# remove the Survived column from the dataset and convert it to an array
# data = data.drop(columns=['Survived']).values
data = data.drop('Survived', 1).values
# compose a sample of the training set from the first 600 rows of the dataset
inputs = data[0:600]
# add a column of imaginary ones for the set
inputs = np.c_[np.ones(600), inputs]
# compose the target set
targets = target_data[0:600]

# from the remaining 114 lines we make a test set
test = data[600:714]
test = np.c_[np.ones(114), test]
targets_test = target_data[600:714]

# learning rate
lr = 0.2
# allowable learning error (** is the degree)
eps = 0.2

# number of nodes in the input layer, taking into account one
# i.e. number of dataset columns +1 imaginary one
input_layer = 5

hidden_layer = 4
hidden_layer2 = 2

output_layer = 1

# initialization of weights depending on the number of nodes in the network layers
w1, w2, w3 = init_weight(input_layer, hidden_layer, hidden_layer2, output_layer)

w1, w2, w3, era, lst = train(inputs, w1, w2, w3, targets, lr, eps)
```

Answer (score 1):

Going by the convention that of weights are (n_neurons, n_inputs), I think the shape of your first hidden layer (W1) should be  -> number of neurons in that layer, number of attributes/features in the sample.

Assuming you are outputing the `Survived` column, your features should be 5.
If there are 4 neurons in that layer, then the shape is (4,5) and your input's shapes will be (n_features, number_of_samples in a batch = m) or (5,m).

In this case the `hidden_in = np.dot(inputs, w1)` should be of shape (4,m).

I believe your error might be that you are including the `Survived` in the input data as well.